# Why would one set the Style property of a control to a template binding referring to just another style?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Why would one set the Style property of a control to a template binding referring to just another style?

I saw the following in a Silverlight book:

```
<charting_primitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
   <Grid Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
</charting_primitives:EdgePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style could contain properties that need to be set in both the EdgePanel and the Grid. For example, perhaps both should have a border and a margin of 20